# Flux: programatic transition on async operation success

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, react-router

My flux workflow is made due [this article](http://mjw56.github.io/handling-asynchronous-data-flow-in-flux/index.html).

```
SignInView ===> AppActionCreators ===> SomeService  
                      |                   ||
                   Promise <============= ||              
                     ||
                     || ======================> SIGN_IN_SUCCESS
```

`SignIn` view invokes `AppActionCreators#signIn` which calls `SomeService`. All `SomeService` methods returns promises, so `AppActionCreators` triggers an action after promise is resolved.

**Question:** What is a true way to do programmatic transition to `IndexView` on `singIn` success? Take a look at code pls:

***AppActionCreators.js:***

```
AppActionCreators = {
    signIn(username, password, signInCb) {
        SomeService.signIn(username, password).then(response => {
            //QUESTION: trigger action and make transition in Store or pass `signInCb` from `SignIn` view?
            AppDispatcher.dispatch({type: ActionTypes.SIGN_IN_SUCCESS, response});
            //Or?
            signInCb();
        });
    }
}
```

***SignIn.react.js***

```
class SignIn extends Component, Router.Navigation {
    handleSubmit(){
        const signInCb = () => this.transitionTo('index', {this.state.data})
        AppActionCreators.signIn(this.state.user,  this.state.password, signInCb);
    }
}
```

---

**Update:** reworded version of the question: use `SIGN_IN_SUCCESS` action + show/hide signIn/Index views vs pass transition callback?

Answer (score 1):

Triggering the action seems more 'fluxy' than the callback mechanism and I would go with that. I think it would make more sense in cases where the State of the application changes after SignIn and by triggering an action, you would allow the stores to appropriately change the state.

For example, setting the signedIn User name/display pic. You would have that in your response and by Dispatching SignInSuccess action, the stores would take those values and set the SignedInUserName property of the application State in the Store and then emit that change.

I am not very familiar with React-Router and am not sure how would you handle state changes with that.

Comment: yeah, I'm absolutelly agree with you. Actually my application works that way at the moment. But what embarrass me in this particular case, is that it isn't enough to `emitChange`  from Store which handle `SIGN_IN_SUCCESS`. Instead I should do transition. That's strange to do view-transition from a store

Comment: relative my comment above: if I do `SIGN_IN_SUCCESS` event & `emitChange` from Store - that's mean that `Index` view should be rendered/subscribed to the Store. So events will show/hide views, instead of transition. That doesn't look like a true way

Comment: I see your point. I am afraid I am not too familiar with React-Router so am not able to comment on the Index view being shown/hidden rather than transitioned.